# What does this mean in YAML?

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm

I have a YAML file used for helm chart:

my_project_deployment.yaml:

```
- name: unzipper.storageMounts.persistent
  value: {{- range $index, $item := .Values.base.storage.netapp.persistent }}{{- if $index }},{{- end }} {{ print .mountPath "/studies_001" }}{{- end }}
```

I know that it is being used for defining properties for specific project. However, I don't understand what it means.

I have a file called dev_value.yaml file which this `.Values` are referencing to.

dev_value.yaml:

```
base:
  storage:
    netapp:
      transient:
        volumeI:
          serverIp:
          imageStorePath: /cache001
          mountPath: /mnt/i
          claim:
            core: pvc-core-cache001
      persistent:
        - name: volumeR
          serverIp:
          imageStorePath: /imagestore001
          mountPath: /mnt/r
          claim:
            core: pvc-core-imagestore001
        - name: volumeS
          serverIp:
          imageStorePath: /imagestore002
          mountPath: /mnt/s
          claim:
            core: pvc-core-imagestore002
```

what would be the `value` in my_project_deployment.yaml? And can anyone please explain how to come up with the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has little to do with YAML, it is Go's [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) syntax. The YAML file is processed by the templating engine before it is parsed by the YAML processor, so by the time the input is parsed as YAML, the value has already been set.

Helm [does have docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/getting_started/) about how templating works and particularly on [values files](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/).

The instructions to the templating engine can be formatted so that it is obvious what happens:

```
{{- range $index, $item := .Values.base.storage.netapp.persistent }}
  {{- if $index }},{{- end }} {{ print .mountPath "/studies_001" }}
{{- end }}
```

It says:

> For each sequence item in the values file at path `base.storage.netapp.persistent`, write a comma if it's not the first one (`$index` will be interpreted as `false` if it's `0`), then print its `mountPath` suffixed by `/studies_001`.

With your values file, you will get

```
value: /mnt/r/studies_001, /mnt/s/studies_001
```